# Recorrer un objeto y sacar una variable selecionada y en otra, las otras que contiene

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de recorrer un objeto que contiene una información, y si bien si se sacar uno de los elementos, no se cómo tengo que hacer para sacar los otros que 'no' he seleccionado. Este es el código:

```
var finalActTabs = {
        fTab1: '#a1, #a2, #a3',
        fTab2: '#b1, #b2, #b3',
        fTab3: '#c1, #c2, #c3'
    };

    for (var k in finalActTabs){
        var selected = finalActTabs[k];
    }
```

De esta manera he seleccionado el que quiero según el orden, pero, cómo hago para meter en otra variable, los datos que contiene el objeto que no han sido llamados en cada recorrido?. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quieres el seleccionado en una variable y los no seleccionados en un objeto o en un array?

Comment: Preferiblemente en un array pero si tiene que estar en un objeto del mismo tipo, tampoco es un inconveniente.

Comment: Me parece que en este tipo de preguntas sería conveniento usar el "fragmento HTML/JavaScript/CSS", por ejemplo, podrías usarlo sólo para javascript y sólo tendrías que agregar console.log(salida) para imprimir la sala en la consola. Mas detalles sobre el fragmento en http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/429/65

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lo tendré en cuenta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrijo, creo que ya te he entendido lo que necesitas.

```
var finalActTabs = {
    fTab1: '#a1, #a2, #a3',
    fTab2: '#b1, #b2, #b3',
    fTab3: '#c1, #c2, #c3'        
};

var j = 0;

for (var k in finalActTabs) {
    if (j === 1) {
        break;
    }
    var selected = finalActTabs[k];
    console.log('seleccionado: ' + finalActTabs[k]);

    // no seleccionados
    var noSeleccionados = finalActTabs; // aqui tienes todos, quitamos el seleccionado y tendrás un array con los elementos no seleccionados
    delete noSeleccionados[k]; // eliminamos la seleccionada
    console.log(noSeleccionados);

    j++;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder tan pronto. Tengo unas dudas, la variable Selected no tendría que ubicarla realmente fuera del bucle?. No podría en un único bucle separar el seleccionado de los sobrantes?. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: En Javascript las variables tienen el ámbito en toda la función, por lo que puedes declararlo dentro del if y llamarla más adelante en la misma función. Aunque si te aclaras mejor, puedes sacarla fuera del if.
Se podría recorrer todo en un único bucle, pero no entiendo tu criterio para establecer un valor en selected, ya que lo haces sí o sí en cada vuelta; necesitaríamos una condición. Editaré mi respuesta y me comentas. Un saludo

Comment: Edito, no puedo pegar tantísimo código.... No se donde ponerlo. Edito de nuevo, me auto respondí para que se vea más claro.

Comment: Te escribo aquí ya que por reputación no puedo comentar en tu respuesta. Según el código, en tu bucle, asignarás un valor a "selected" cuando "j" sea "0" y "2", siendo reemplazado cuando sea "2" Es decir no puedes tener más de uno seleccionado si lo asignas en una variable única, ya que sobreescribes su valor. No te entiendo muy bien, ¿cuándo necesitas hacer el recuento de elementos no seleccionados? ¿Durante el bucle? ¿O una vez hayas salido de tu bucle?

Comment: Durante el bucle, es decir, haré un único bucle, una única pasada y en esa pasada, generar el elemento seleccionado y los no seleccionados, y en éste paso del bucle al finalizar llamaré al contructor y le daré el seleccionado y los no seleccionados. Es decir, ftab2 el seleecionado y ftab1 y ftab3 los no seleccionados.

Comment: He reconstruido la respuesta, creo que ya te he entendido bien. Cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Perfecto, esto buscaba :)  casi lo había logrado por otras vías pero esta se adecúa más a mis necesidades. Gracias!.

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para f_bartstar:

```
var finalActTabs = {
            fTab1: '#a1, #a2, #a3',
            fTab2: '#b1, #b2, #b3',
            fTab3: '#c1, #c2, #c3'        
        };

        var j = 0;

        for (var k in finalActTabs) {
            if (j === 1) {
                break;
            }
            var selected = finalActTabs[k];
            console.log('seleccionado: ' + finalActTabs[k]);
            j++;
        }

        // -- inicio código añadido --

        var noSeleccionados = []; // indices no seleccionados

        for (var k in finalActTabs) { // recorremos de nuevo
            if (finalActTabs[k] != selected) { // si no es el seleccionado
                noSeleccionados.push(finalActTabs[k]); // añadimos al array de no seleccionados
            }
        }
        // recorremos el nuevo array
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            console.log('no seleccionado: ' + noSeleccionados[i]);
        }
```

Esto es lo que sucede en una pasada. Creo que voy a extenderme para que se entienda mejor.

Voy a crear una nueva instancia por cada ver que recorremos el objeto finalActTabs, por tanto en una variable irá el elemento seleccionado y en otra, la suma del resto de elementos, aunque sea un array le aplico un join o algo así y listo. El caso es que no consigo seleccionar o filtrar las demás.